# Can I read a file in windows in c++ without locking folder containing the file

Tags: c++, windows, locking, createfile

I have a c++ program that continuously reads a log file(ex: C:/temp/file.txt). However, while the program is running I want to be able to delete/rename the folder('temp') containing the file being monitored.

Currently, I'm using CreateFile().

```
        CreateFile(
                  szFilename,
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                  NULL)
```

I get the following error whenever I delete/rename the folder:
"The action can't be completed because the folder or file in it is open in another program"

Is there a way to read/open a file without locking it?

Comment: no way. if you have opened file for read in folder, nobody else can open this folder with `DELETE` access. but this is require for rename/delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a hardlink to this file somewhere else using [`CreateHardLinkW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860(v=vs.85).aspx) and open it instead of original file. This way the original file (which is actually a hardlink as well) and the folder containing it can be renamed / deleted but the file itself will be still accessible. Note that this method implies some restrictions on type of underlying file system, hardlink location, and access rights.